# Find a file, find a line in a file and change that line

Tags: powershell

I need to find files on a server that contain a specific line of text, I then need to replace that line of text with a new one.

surfed the internet and tried several methods to write to the file.

```
$path = "C:\users\
$filename = "myfile.ini"

$searchString="Program=C:\Program Files (x86)\Over\Here"
$newString="Program=C:\Program Files (x86)\Here

Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Recurse -Filter $filename -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | foreach-object {

(Get-Content $_.FullName) | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace [regex]::Escape($searchString), [regex]::Escape($newString) } | Set-Content $_.FullName

}
```

I'm expecting my file to look like this.

```
Program=C:\Program Files (x86)\Here
```

But I get this.

```
Program=C:\\\Program\ Files\ (x86\\)\\\Here
```

I suspect it has to do with the "\" in the file path, but I can't figure out out to get them to behave correctly.

Comment: You only need to regex escape `$SearchString`. The replacement value is not a regex. It is just a string.

Comment: Yeah, that did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't escape the second argument.

```
 -replace [regex]::Escape($searchString), $newString
```

Comment: took out the regex in the $newstring and it work.  Thanks!

Comment: @js2010: I will remove my comment then. You can remove yours